# select2 ajax not returning correct value in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 3.5.1

.I have a text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSerach" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
```

which is converted to select2.

I want to pass parameter to my backend to load dynamically result when user click a search Name it will go to back end,fetch data to select,the result will be shown as textbox result

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myurl = 'ajaxOndemandsinSelect2.aspx/getSpareParts';
            $('#txtSerach').select2({

                ajax: {
                    url: myurl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    type:'POST',
                    quietMillis: 100,
                    data: function (term) {
                        var dt = {
                            id: "id",
                            text: "text"
                        };
                        return JSON.stringify({ "name":term });
                    },
                    results: function (data) {

                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

and my webmethod in asp.net is

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Select2Data>  getSpareParts(string name)
{
    //q 2term   2
    var db = new WaltonCrmEntities();
    var dataOfSelect= db.SpareParts.Select(x => new Select2Data
    {
        id = x.ItemID,
        text = x.ItemName
    }).ToList();
    return dataOfSelect;

}
```

But ajax is not returning correct result !!! see my screen shot
[image]

[image]

Comment: your response should be json, not html.

Comment: how to confirm a json response in select2

Comment: seems that your webmethod is not called but instead the whole page is returned again in response to the ajax request

Comment: it's not about select2 it's about your ajax request, `contentType: "application/json"` put this to insure youre request just return json

Comment: No web method is not calling.I put a break point but it does not hit by ajax

Comment: Still the result is same @shayanypn

Comment: Is the text box inside a form? Maybe hitting enter is posting and refreshing the page.

Comment: Yes i text box in form and i replaced but still no luck @wero

Comment: it's amaze. your ajax request, return current page html. your url `/getSparePart` should just return josn??

Comment: AJAX request and web method are both working fine .i tested it by jQuery ajax but with select2 i have no luck :(

Comment: same issue tried a lot but not get call webmethod

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki Use select2 with Web Service Handler (.asmx) . I will not work with normal webmethod